# Kubernetes ingress in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kops

Please, help me to deal with accessibility of my simple application.
I created YML with an application:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-test
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: gcr.io/kubernetes-e2e-test-images/echoserver:2.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myapp-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
   - name: http
     protocol: TCP
     port: 80
     targetPort: 8080
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /hello
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Then I created k8s cluster via kops, like this, all services k8s have risen, I can enter the master:

```
kops create cluster \
--node-count = 2 \
--node-size = t2.micro \
--master-size = t2.micro \
--master-count = 1 \
--zones = us-east-1a \
--name = ${KOPS_CLUSTER_NAME}
```

In the end, I can't get to the application on port 80, it write's that the connection is refused!
Can someone tell me, what is the problem? This yml above fully works, but in the minikube environment(

Comment: Do you have an nginx ingress controller deployed? And do you have DNS set up pointing to the ingress controller's external IP?

Comment: All what you see here, this is all, that I deployed to k8s( I just have R53 hosted zone with domain, there kops created for me 4 records, one of them is api.domain_name.com, which bundled to master node ip address. Could you sent me minimal workable config for ingress controler? Because a lot of guids are not clear for me(

Comment: Actually you have service type NodePort so it should be accessible even without Ingress. Can you try to hit it by IP address? There are different ways of setting up ingress so not sure I can do better than point to a guide such as https://medium.com/kokster/how-to-setup-nginx-ingress-controller-on-aws-clusters-7bd244278509

Comment: You could also try without any Ingress (i.e. remove the Ingress).

Comment: I also tried to visit my app via ip address before, the same error( Can't understand what k8s/aws want from me

Comment: If you choose NodePort that should work but right now you don't have an external port set. That is set with 'nodePort' not 'port' or 'targetPort'.

Comment: If you choose Ingress you want an nginx ingress controller. NodePort and Ingress are different approaches for exposing a Service externally so you want to pick one or the other to try

Comment: I need ingress exactly and I configured it, it workable in minikube but I want understand why it wan't work in AWS k8s cluster.

Comment: Your ingress rule is matching traffic to `myapp.com` only.

I presume you are attempting to access it using curl or a web browser, but without an example of the request you are attempting to issue it is difficult to help you any further.

It would also be helpful to see the describe output of the ingress, deployment and services.

Comment: 1. I added myapp.com to my /etc/hosts with ip address of master
2. I added also for testing 80 port for every sg, which kops created, because by default there open for world 443, 22 and many other ports just for the local network
3. Write domain name myapp.com in browser and getting CONNECTION REFUSED error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you have created an Ingress resource, but I presume you have not deployed prior the NGINX Ingress Controller for your on-premise cluster on AWS. It's explained [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws) on how to do this in general.

**In case** of Kubernetes cluster bootsrapped with **Kops**, things are more complex, and it requires you to modify an existing cluster, to use a dedicated kops add-on: `kube-ingress-aws-controller`, as explained on their github project page [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/tree/9da7daf7b6ecb6495b77db21f5f35636529634b1/addons/kube-ingress-aws-controller)

In current form your app can be reached only via Node/AWS Instance external IP on port assigned from default range (30000-32767). You can check currently assign port via `kubectl get svc myapp-service`), but this requires opening it first on firewall (default Inbound rules deny All traffic apart SSH). Based on you deploy/service manifest files:

```
NAME            TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
myapp-service   NodePort   100.64.187.80   <none>        80:32076/TCP   37m
```

with port 32076 open in inbound rules of Security Group assigned to my instance I can now reach app on NodePort:

```
curl <node_external_ip>:32076

Hostname: myapp-test-f87bcbd44-8nxpn
Pod Information:
-no pod information available-
Server values:
```

Comment: Please check my updated question, I was wrong regarding NodePort (app will be exposed on port 30000-32767), there is also a dedicated how-to guide for kops specific Ingress-Controller add-on.

Comment: Thank you so for detailed answer! I understood my problem, will try to rise up kube-ingress-aws-controller
And you were right, my app was accessible via NodePort, when I add rule with port number to master SG

Comment: So, I get a big success in this, just one question, may be you know.. can I disable ssl checking for aws-controller? Because I'm getting an error in aws-controller like this:
`Failed to find certificate for hostname myapp.com: no matching certificate found
2018/12/19 16:46:34 No certificates found for [myapp.com]`
And I think because of this, I can't reach my app right now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure the nginx ingress, you can follow the document https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/install-nginx-ingress-controller/ which might need to create IAM role and associate to Service Account.
In case of using AWS Application load balancer, you can also have to create an IAM role https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.5.4/docs/install/iam_policy.json. The permission from the Link allow AWS ALB controller can access AWS resources during provisioning ingress.
After that, you can using helm or yaml file to deploy the ALB controller.
You can also follow the link to deploy the AWS load balancer controller  https://sofreview.vercel.app/posts/deploy-aws-load-balancer-controller-ingress-eks